# Tips for studying Android

Tags: android, gps, database-connection

I joined a company recently and they have requested me to develop a few applications for Android. I've never seen it before - though I'm familiar with Java, so the programmatic syntax is familiar to me - and I'd like to know if there is a good site/textbook/whatever where I could learn how to program for Android OS - the simpler the better!

In particular, I'm searching for some way to allow me to use Android to do 2 things - to get a GPS location on a regular basis and to get an application connecting with a remote database. These are my priorities at the moment, but this doesn't mean you can't indicate me a knowledge source that doesn't have these on it. I do need to learn to program on this system, and I'll be thankful for whatever you indicate me. But if you happen to know where I could find these 2 items, please don't be shy and let me know.

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Honestly, the Android Developer site is really good. It has a lot of good info. Coming from iOS, the concepts were a bit different, but once I wrapped my head around it - it wasn't an issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've asked three different questions here. One is about how to learn about android which is off-topic (please have a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)) also take a look at this: [Learning Android Resources on PSE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android+learning) which might help. The other two are somewhat vague questions on how to use GPS and connect to a database with no attempt so far to do this yourself. So unfortunately this question needs to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, the best place to start is right on the Android Developers site. Although you might not feel like you need it at first, spending the due time to do some of the simple tutorials to get used to how the UI works and how the Android framework and Activity lifecycle works is extremely important.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first and the best start point to the Android developing, the Android Developers site (Official).
Here is some link for you:
developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

developer.android.com/reference/packages.html

developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsSatellite.html

developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I haven't find any better source of information than the official android developers page: http://developer.android.com/index.html

And here SO has a lot of interesting topics...

I also recomend you to investigate scripting in android with python, it's awesome the easy way to get things working...

Look at this code:

```
import android, time
droid = android.Android()
droid.startLocating()
time.sleep(10)
location = droid.readLocation()
```

now location is an dictionary with your latitude, longitude, altitude, speed, and some other information... you'll find everything about scripting in android here: http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/